# how to work image from 2 level folder

Tags: php, image, mysqli

I have a problem with my queries doesnt work the image of the source, so i have root/travel-page.php in the root folder and on the query i want put a image from root/travel/imagini/picture.jpg .. i putted all the html link http://exemple.com/travel/imagini/picture.jpg , but doesnt work

the page.php i redirectionat using htacces  in travel/queryLink.php

So my question is if i can do something to make those image to appear if is 2 level of folder diference between the page and the image

if i try to call the image from root/images/picture.jpg - is work.. because is only a level between thoose.

```
RewriteRule ^travel/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) ./page.php?pid=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

**I FIXED the problem**, maybe someone will have the same problem with the image what not show after the `RewriteRule`

**i needed to add** `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

so the right code is this...dont forget to request the filename how i did it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^travel/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) ./page.php?pid=$1 [NC,L]
```